# Winstore path and password

Tags: c#, keystore, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using Confluent.Kafka library in C#.Net

But while passing schema registry I need to pass keystore path and keystore password

I don't have any idea how to get path and password from Keystore on windows.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve a password from windows and pass it to kafka client?
Do you want to log on to kafka in your client?

Comment: Hi Siraf , need to password as sslkeystorepassword to kafka while making request

Comment: You need to create your SSL certs with a password. We cannot give it to you since we didn't make the certs. Refer https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/TlsAuth

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer it helped me to get the right direction but now getting error 40401 i.e. subject ‘xxx-xxx-acc-jason-key’ not found

Comment: Well, is you producer actually using Avro keys? Those aren't very common, so maybe your consumer shouldn't use Avro for the KeyDeserializer property?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes producer is using Avro keys.key is registred at consumer end but not getting what is going wrong also made auto schema register = false